# Why my swap area is set to zero in Ubuntu Server 18.04.2?

Tags: swap

By checking the swap size in my Ubuntu server I observed that is set to zero.  Since it was installed in very basic configuration from AWS EC2,  I'm not sure if I had to do additional steps to adjust swap size area.

I run the following commands and got the below results :

```
    # grep Swap /proc/meminfo
       SwapCached:            0 kB
       SwapTotal:             0 kB
       SwapFree:              0 kB

    # swapon -s 

    #  free -m
                     total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           7975         187        7059           0         728        7549
    Swap:             0           0           0

# cat /proc/swaps
  Filename                         Type            Size    Used    Priority
```

Is it normal to have a swap area set to zero ?   If it is not, what should I do to fix it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, some cloud (VPS) providers disable the swap in their (modified) installations. Nowadays Ubuntu support swap file, thus you do not need a separate partition for swap. To enable the swap via swap file follow these steps:

```bsh
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile  # Create a 'swap-file'; 4G in this case
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile        # Set the necessary file permissions
ls -lh /swapfile                # Check
sudo mkswap /swapfile           # Mark the file as 'swap'
sudo swapon /swapfile           # Enable the 'swap'
sudo swapon --show              # Check
free -h                         # Another check
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and make the changes permanent. Use these commands to do the changes:

```bsh
sudo sed 's/^.*swap.*$//' /etc/fstab -i.bak                # Remove the previous swap entries 
                                                           # and create a backup copy of the file
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab # Add a new entry
```

Or edit `/etc/fstab` and add the the following entry *manually*:

```bsh
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

That is it.

---

Ideas for additional tweaks (I would prefer to use the default settings for normal swap usage):

- Change the frequency of *RAM to SWAP* data copy:

  ```bsh
  sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10    # value 0-100: low value low frequency
  cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness     # Check
  ```
- Change the frequency of *Cache flush*:

  ```bsh
  sudo sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 # 0-100: high value high frequency
  cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure  # Check
  ```
- Make the above changes permanent:

  ```bsh
  sudo cp /etc/sysctl.conf{,.bak} # Create a backup copy of the file '/etc/sysctl.conf'
  echo -e '\nCustom settings: value 0-100; default 100\nvm.swappiness=10\nvm.vfs_cache_pressure=50' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
  ```

  Or edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the the following entries *manually*:

  ```bsh
  # Custom settings: value 0-100; default 100
  vm.swappiness=10
  vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
  ```

Comment: that is it !!  I followed your clear and complete instructions and I could solve my problem ! Many thanks !   Now I can see that my Ubuntu server has a swap area enabled and it is working since  I run ou of RAM during a processing and immediately Ubuntu started to use SWAP and continue to process my application.

Comment: However I observed a strange behaviour in Apache2 (2.4.29) related to swap area.  When running my application as an apache module, it reached the RAM limit then started to use swap BUT when my application has finished the RAM memory consumed continued the same (i.e. high) as well as part of the swap area were still occupied ! Is that normal in Apache under Ubuntu server ?

Comment: Hi, @JRG. Probably Apache keeps some data in the RAM for further fast access, however the Linux kernel is really good with the hardware utilization and it will free such unused RAM when need it.

Comment: Hei @pa4080, for sure your answer was useful and right. I checked the grey tick  right now. Sorry for not doing this before.  Thank you !

Comment: Spas let me ask you a question, do you know about Apache mpm modules parametrization ?

Comment: Hello, @JRG, I'm not familiar with Apache mpm modules fine tuning.